# Uso correcto de clases y métodos en Python

Tags: python

Con Qt5 Designer hice una única MainWindow, mi pregunta es: Sí esta bien que este dentro de la clase como método, la función; Ya que le pase porciones de código (como si fuera una subrutina). Solamente complete la primer función de la clase.
El código lo que hace es simple ingresa al sitio y descarga los archivos solicitados.
Espero se entienda la pregunta, hace 2 o 3 meses que estoy con programación Python.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.action_Mercados.triggered.connect(self.mercados)
            self.action_Saldos.triggered.connect(self.saldos)
            self.actionC_obranzas.triggered.connect(self.cobranzas)
            self.actionSal_ir.triggered.connect(self.salir)
            self.actionAcerca_de.triggered.connect(self.acerca_de)

     def mercados(self):
            # Creamos una sesion de Chrome
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.maximize_window()
            
            # Accedemos a la pagina web
            driver.get ('https://www.xxx.com.ar/')
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="user_login"]').send_keys(usuario)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="user_pass"]').send_keys(clave)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="btnacceder_CD"]').click()
    
            ## Realizacion de Consultas ##
    
            # Operaciones
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="myNavbar"]/ul/li[1]').click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="myNavbar"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[5]/a').click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_chlCuentas_RB1_I_D"]').click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="accordion"]/div[11]/div[1]/span/i').click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCtaCte_CD"]').click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    
            # Descarga Archivo
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDescargar"]/span').click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
            # Sale del sitio
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/header/section/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a').click()
            
            # Sale del Navegador
            driver.quit()
         
        def saldos(self):
            pass
        
        def cobranzas(self):
            pass
        
        def acerca_de(self):
            pass
        
        def salir(self):
            sys.exit()
                    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        window = MainWindow()
        window.show()
        app.exec_()
```

Comment: No entendi.. a que te referis con subrutinas?

Comment: Ahí modifique y replantee la pregunta.